# Remove styrofoam protection from under the fridge by myself

Tags: home, kitchen, appliances, safety

I have ordered a new fridge and it came packed in styrofoam protection, including on the bottom.

[image]

I need to remove that but I don't know how. The fridge is to heavy to lift by myself. Even if a friend helps me I'm not sure how to remove it without risking to damage the fridge.

So how can I safely remove it?

Comment: Do you know if it runs all the way under, or if it's just an open frame held in place by the feet?

Comment: As we repeatedly got the question: No, it’s not a good idea to just leave it there. A fridge creates heat on the outside and to avoid overheating and potential damage, you need to ensure sufficient airflow. Blocking the bottom part can significantly hinder that, as can placing the fridge too close to a wall or other furniture. See the manual for minimum distances.

Comment: The DIY Home Improvement site suggests this: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/211364/how-to-unpack-the-base-of-a-refrigerator. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it:

1. Tilt fridge **a bit**, so it will stand only on one side of styrofoam.
2. Kick "free" side of styrofoam, to break it out and kick out from under the fridge.
3. Tilt the fridge to the other side.
4. Kick second half of styrofoam.

---

**WARNING** You need to be big and strong enough to be sure you can actually hold it when you kick your styrofoam. Tilting too much, kicking too strong or holding too weakly may lead to damaged equipment and to injury.

*This is just obligatory warning, the fact I had no problems in the past does not mean it is safe for all. I'm tall and heavy. But it worked for me like a charm.*

---

If you have a friend to help you, one of you should tilt the fridge, and other should break and pull away styrofoam. Much safer that way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Molot in as much as you need to tilt it, kick/pull/break half out, then tilt it the other way to remove the other half.

However, on the details I feel you need more...

1. Looking at your flooring & knowing what the feet on that kind of appliance can be like, I wouldn't even start this task until you get some glider feet to go underneath.
   Google "appliance feet gliders" for the self-adhesive teflon type [cheap & really quite good] or  "appliance gliders" which will include 'trucks' you can roll the appliance on.
2. Slide the whole thing, styrofoam & all, towards a wall, maybe 9" to 1' away. Tilt it towards the wall. That way you can't push it right over & it will remain relatively stable whilst it's there.
3. Once you've removed the first half of the styrofoam, you put the gliders on the first pair of feet that unveils, allowing you to spin it round to do the second side [again leaning it on the wall, but be careful, it will be more slippery this time], add the second gliders & then you can manoeuvre the fridge into place without wrecking the floor, & also with about ¼ as much physical effort.

I'd still get a friend to help, even doing it this way.